# python: is there an isError function?

Tags: python

is there a function that will return `true` if `some_function` returns an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are times you want to ask whether an object is an Exception (for example, when you get the result of a task back from a celery type process). You can do that using:

`isinstance(x, Exception)`

Answer (score 4):

No. Python uses exceptions to handle errors, and these are caught using `try...catch` blocks.

In other words, what is your definition of an error? `False`? `Null`? `""`?

#### Edit:

To answer your question in the comment, there is no well-defined way of comparing, say, `"1.1"` and `"1.2"`. This is intentional, because *there is no obvious ordering on strings*. Now in fact, Python does support comparing strings, but it uses lexicographic (alphabetical) ordering, which isn't what you want. This is because these strings are *semantically* `float`s -- they represent numbers. Now the real problem is that they shouldn't have been strings in the first place (because they're numbers!), but sometimes you can't fix that. So instead, turn them into numbers:

```
float(1.1) > float(1.2)
```

Comment: ok so the problem: how do i compare two strings. for example how a=1.1 and b=1.2, how do i know which one is greater?

Comment: Define "greater" in terms of strings. Is "200" greater than "1000"? Is "999" greater than "Zackary"?

Comment: You need to cast them both to numbers, in this case `float` s, because there's no way of comparing strings. Do `float(a) > float(b)`.

Comment: You *can* compare strings lexicographically with the regular comparison operators.  As @Lasse said, it depends what kind of comparison you want.

Comment: Sorry -- you know what I meant =p! Have elaborated in the post.

Comment: @katriealex: How do you know what the OP wants/needs? His data may be paragraph numbers limited to "\d\.\d". Who says they are "semantically float"?

Comment: OK, so I generalised a little bit too much; based on the post history I don't s/he's doing anything very complicated. I guess it would be more correct to say that they are semantically `decimal` but that this is best represented in a builtin by `float`.

Answer (score 2):

In python you do error checking with exceptions:

```
try:
    some_function()
except Exception:
    print "error"
```

You need to define some_function() to `raise Exception` if an error happened.

Answer (score 2):

No you do **try..except ErrorType as e:** and then if you enter the exception handler, you know that the type you chose error happened.
 [Built-in Exceptions](http://docs.python.org/library/exceptions.html)

To compare two strings containing both numbers in same amount of decimals you can do:

```
print ("%20s" % first) >= ("%20s" % second)
```

More general way is to do normal comparison but for equality use absolute value of difference comparison.

```
numbers= ("1.2","1.3")
a,b= (float(num) for num in numbers)
print("Bigger or equal" if a>b else "Smaller")
```